# Neo4j : Predicat ALL. Check if a key is greater than a string

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 3.0.6 and I want to return the values when key of my relationship is greater than '2015-02'. Here is my query in Cypher :

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]->() 
WHERE ALL(key in keys(r)  WHERE key>'2015-02')
RETURN r['key']
```

It returns anything. I don't knwo where is the problem

Otherwise :

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]->()
Unwind keys(r) as k
with '2015-02'<k as m,k
RETURN r['k'],m
```

But this one retruns the result of my test (true or false) and as value : null. So, it doesn't filter my keys and return their values

Comment: Key or key-value is greater than a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are used to delimit a string (i.e. characters part of the data, not of the query language itself), so `r['k']` means the value of the property of `r` **named** `k`.

What you want is `r[k]`, meaning the value of the property of `r` which **name is in the `k` variable**.

Your queries should be

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]->() 
WHERE ALL(key in keys(r)  WHERE key>'2015-02')
RETURN r[key] // No quotes
```

and

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]->()
UNWIND keys(r) as k
WITH '2015-02' < k as m, k
RETURN r[k], m // No quotes either
```

---

**Update**

As noted in the comments, in the first query `key` only exists in the context of the `all()` function. A more correct query would be:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]->() 
UNWIND keys(r) AS key
WITH r, key
WHERE key > '2015-02'
RETURN r[key]
```

and it's now almost the second query.

Comment: Thank you for explainng. Now, I saw the difference but when executing the first one.  I got an error : Variable `key` not defined. Is it defined only in predicat ALL? Thank you

Comment: Yes, my bad, `key` only exists in the context of `all()`.

Comment: Thank you for updating your post but I think it's the clause 'With' rather than 'Where'

Comment: It's not one or the other, it's both.

Comment: Also, would you mind [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) on the answers people provide you with, if they're helpful?